# How to pass data from Helper Mysql Promises nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql2

i have a problem passing data from folder helper

database.js

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'localhost',
    port:'3306',
    user: 'root',
    database: '',
    password: '',
    dateStrings: true
});

module.exports = pool.promise();
```

helper.js

```
const Master = require('../models/inspection');

module.exports = {
    getLokasi: function (x) {
        Master.fetchAll()
            .then(([result]) => {
                const hasil = result;
                return hasil;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

model inspection.js

```
const db = require('../util/database');

module.exports = class Master {
    constructor(si_id) {
        this.si_id  = si_id;
        
    }

    static fetchAll() {
        return db.execute('SELECT * FROM mt_analisa_resiko');
    }

  };
```

controller

```
const helpers = require('../../util/helpers');

exports.getInspectionDetail = (req, res, next) => {
    const test = helpers.getLokasi();
    console.log(test);
}
```

the problem always return undefined

but when i console.log(hasil) on helper.js it return the data. How do i pass the data from helper so i can used the data on my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the promise:

```
module.exports = {
    getLokasi: function (x) {
        return Master.fetchAll()
            .then(([result]) => {
                const hasil = result;
                return hasil;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

You should be able to access the returned value then:

```
exports.getInspectionDetail = async (req, res, next) => {
    const result = await helpers.getLokasi();
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: can you help me how to return the promise. thanks alot

Comment: Take a closer look at my answer. I've added `return` before `Master.fetchAll()`. It should worke fine with this.

Comment: thanks for your help. I already change the code when i check it return 
Promise { <pending> }.